# How to update Python on Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I recently downloaded Python 3.4.1, however my Mac still refers to an older version (i.e. typing in /usr/bin/python in terminal displays the older version). I don't know much of any Unix, how can I replace the old version of Python?

Comment: it is most likely either /usr/local/bin/python3 or /opt/local/bin/python3 depending on how you installed it

Comment: `/bin/python` or whatever it's equivalent is is normally a link to the actual python version, and changing it system wide to a non backwards compatible python will likely break other things you have installed.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who commented, jwillis0720's solution worked out.